# How to split 2 or more delimited columns in a single row to multiple rows using Talend

Tags: talend, data-migration, csv

I am trying to move data from a CSV file to DB table. There are 2 delimited columns in the CSV file (separated by ";"). I would like to create a row for each of the delimited values at matching indexes as shown below. Assumption is that both columns will contain same number of delimited items.

Example CSV Input:

```
Labels     Values
A;B;C      1;2;3
D          4
F;G        5;6
```

Expected Output:

```
Labels     Values
A          1
B          2
C          3
D          4
E          5
F          6
```

How can I achieve this? I have tried using tNormalize but this only works for a single column. Also I tried 2 successive tNormalize nodes but as expected it resulted in unwanted combinations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read your CSV file with a tfileinputdelimited, and 
define your schema for the file.

Assuming you are using MySQL , also drop a tMysqlOutput component on you desinger to save your parsed file to the DB.

Comment: my issue is not with saving the CSV contents to SQL, but with transforming the input from a tFileInputDelimited node to the expected values as shown above. Can you please explain how that may be done?